# mitmproxy record to outfile utf8 encoding error

Tags: mitmproxy

I am using mitmproxy and want to record every request and reponse to file,so I use "-w" option just as following:

```
mitmproxy -b 192.168.1.107 -p 9527 -w ~/Desktop/aaa.txt
```

but when I open the 'aaa.txt',it display unreadable content which is just as following:

```
[x§‡:ÖáHi4GÐL¿¤Ìé4ÎæyùÍ§q¼<µYÂ&É‹¶Mñ+GÒ‡i8
avÅÆdT£<_‰»ÚÀ—æÏÂÓSòo“çˆ$B6KƒßÛVÚ¼rq{”2w.®NÉRhÔ…x)¥qÕ¾0‡8éÙOøóŸüÍ—òÛ_þãnñ—‡"Ä‚NqiŠ¬@JÔî"œE§"CJ&0‡Í*NCBé   r:G£O1yùè“æRQB4
```

I also try the script:https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/master/examples/flowwriter.py
it still doesn't work, so is there some encoding error?

Comment: If memory serves then mitmproxy records in pcap format — http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap/pcap.html ; however I'm not confident enough of that recollection to make this an answer.

Comment: @Tommy: mitmproxy has a custom serialization format, we do not save pcaps.

Comment: Then I'll leave the comment as otherwise yours will look odd but at least be happy that my judgement about posting an answer was correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mitmproxy -w` writes a serialized (not primarily human-readable) dump file that can be read again using `-r`. If the content of a message are e.g. gzip-encoded, you'll see gzip-encoded data in the dumpfile. If you want human-readable output to a text file, I'd suggest running

`mitmdump -r ~/Desktop/aaa.txt -n -dd`

Explanation:

`-r`: Read an existing dump file
`-n`: Do not start a proxy server
`-d`: increase output details/verbosity (`-ddd` if you don't want contents to be cut off)